# custom field group , image field value not displayed on front-end

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2 to make a field-group for my products page, here is the code for the metabox

```js
function cmb2_sample_metaboxes( array $meta_boxes ) {

 // Start with an underscore to hide fields from custom fields list
 $prefix = '_cmb2_';



 

 /**
  * Repeatable Field Groups
  */
 $meta_boxes['field_group'] = array(
  'id'           => 'field_group',
  'title'        => __( 'Manage your products here', 'cmb2' ),
  'object_types' => array( 'page', ),
  'fields'       => array(
   array(
    'id'          => $prefix . 'repeat_group',
    'type'        => 'group',
    'options'     => array(
     'group_title'   => __( 'Product {#}', 'cmb2' ), // {#} gets replaced by row number
     'add_button'    => __( 'Add Another Product', 'cmb2' ),
     'remove_button' => __( 'Remove Product', 'cmb2' ),
     'sortable'      => true, // beta
    ),
    'fields'      => array(
     array(
      'name' => 'Product Name',
      'id'   => 'product_name',
      'type' => 'text',
     ),
     array(
      'name' => 'Product Description',
      'description' => 'Write a short description for this Product',
      'id'   => 'product_description',
      'type' => 'textarea_small',
     ),
     array(
      'name' => 'Product Image',
      'id'   => 'product_image',
      'type' => 'file',
     ),
     array(
      'name' => __( 'Image Caption', 'cmb2' ),
      'desc' => __( 'Write a short description for the image', 'cmb2' ),
      'id'   => 'image_caption',
      'type' => 'text_medium',
     ),
    ),
   ),
  ),
 );

 // Add other metaboxes as needed

 return $meta_boxes;
}
```

and i want to display it on the following html markup

```html
<div class="container products">
        <div class="row">
          <?php

            $products = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_cmb2_repeat_group', true );

            foreach ( (array) $products as $key => $product ) {

                $img = $title = $caption = '';

                if ( isset( $product['product_name'] ) )
                    $title = esc_html( $product['product_name'] );


                if ( isset( $product['product_image'] ) ) {            
                    $img = wp_get_attachment_image( $product['product_image'], 'thumbnail', null, array(
                        'class' => 'img-thumbnail',
                    ) );
                }
                $caption = isset( $product['image_caption'] ) ? wpautop( $product['image_caption'] ) : '';

                // Do something with the data
            

          ?>
          <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 box">
            <a href="#">
              <?php echo $img; ?>
              <span class="rotate-caption hidden-xs">
                <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
                <hr>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,</p>
              </span>
            </a>
          </div>
 
          <?php } ?>
```

the problem only with the image field it is not displaying on the front-end , when i inspected the element on chroome there was no img tag , `<?php echo $title; ?>` worked fine and is displayed on the front-end , so i was wondering what i am doing wrong with the image.

Answer (score 2):

Solved, i found out what i am doing wrong , image id should be product_image_id according to the docs. there must be '_id' added to the end of your image id you have set for the field.